# Implementation of 'Difference of Gaussians' in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, gimp

For a Project I am trying to extract pretty dim contours from an Image. While playing around with GIMP I found a way to extract and threshold those contours beautifully using "Difference of Gaussians" with radius1=1 and radius2=25 (or even greater). However when trying to reimplement this workflow in OpenCV my results are not as good as with GIMP (dimmer, less crisp):
[Difference in DoG Implementation OpenCV vs. GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BEVt.jpg)

I have skimmed through GIMPs Sourcecode and found that in the newest Version (which I am using) there are two implementations of DoG. I used the non-legacy one, which is based on GEGL, Sourcecode can be found [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/blob/master/operations/common/difference-of-gaussians.c).

My implementation as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970035/gimp-difference-of-gaussians-in-opencv):

```
{
  Mat g1, g2, result;
  GaussianBlur(input, g1, Size(0, 0), gaussian1, gaussian1);
  GaussianBlur(input, g2, Size(0, 0), gaussian2, gaussian2);
  cv::subtract(g1, g2, result);
  return result;
}
```

So as you can see, my implementation and the GEGL one are superficially identical, however the results are vastly different.
I already tried playing around with `cv::equalizeHist()`to enhance the contrast of my result, but this also did not yield anything usable.

I would gladly appreciate any ideas on what is going on here.
Thanks!

Comment: This is related... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54973179/2836621

Comment: Yeah I read through that thread, but from what I could gather they never found a solution.

Comment: Could be dependent on linear v.s. gamma-corrected. In Gimp, the 2.10 results (linear AFAIK) are much better than the ones in the 2.8 version (gamma-corrected). [Example](https://imgur.com/ePOeN47)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that looks promising, could you elaborate on this? What is happening in Gimp that I need to reproduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to (partially) achieve what I wanted, thanks to a Pointer by @xenoid.

What I did now is take the Codesnippet from above and simply multiply the Mat `result` by a factor. 
Full Codesnippet:

```
cv::Mat differenceOfGaussians(cv::Mat input, int gaussian1, int gaussian2)
{
  Mat g1, g2, result;
  GaussianBlur(input, g1, Size(0, 0), gaussian1, gaussian1);
  GaussianBlur(input, g2, Size(0, 0), gaussian2, gaussian2);
  cv::subtract(g1, g2, result);
  result = result * gammaInt;
  return result;
}
```

gammaInt being a global int variable controlled via slider.
The result (for a better image with some Contrastamplification done by the camera itself) can be found here: [DoG with linear amplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8653.jpg)

Comment: As far as I understand it when Gimp works on linear data, it undoes the gamma correction, so `linear=pow(initial,1/gamma)`, where initial is in `[0,1.0[` and gamma is around 2.2.